# ¿Como mandar colocar un dato específico en una celda de una JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, jtextfield

Suponiendo se tiene el dato:
int cantidad = 5;

Deseo que el dato cantidad, sea impreso en una celda específica (cualquiera) de un JTable. El objetivo de esto es imprimir diferentes Label's en celdas sus correspondientes de una tabla.

Comment: Si editas tu pregunta y colocas fragmentos del código de tu JTable y de la parte donde obtienes el int cantidad sería más facil ayudarte. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para insertar valores a un JTable tienes que hacelo de la siguiente manera: 
**JTable tuTabla = new JTable(); 

tuTabla.setValueAt(cantidad, row, column);**
En donde cantidad es el valor a insertar, row la fila y column la columna.
Nada más eso, si es que entendí bien tu pregunta

Comment: Todo perfecto. Solo una duda más, si yo ya tengo previamente diseñado un formulario, y tengo un JPanel en donde quiero que aparezca la tabla al apretar un botón, ¿Qué comando debe ocuparse?

Comment: A ver si entiendo, quieres que al apretar un botón aparezca en tu panel una tabla? Si es así lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente. Como un JTable lo colocas en un JScrollPane, con tu objeto scrollPane debes hacer esto: scrollPane.setVisible(false);, y al apretar el botón devuelve su visibilidad scrollPane.setVisible(true).

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego también un método para que te sea más facil realizar el cambio de visibilidad de tu tabla. Le pasas la tabla y el boolean a establecer la visibilidad:

```
public void setTableVisible(JTable table, boolean visible) {
    table.setVisible(visible);
    table.getTableHeader().setVisible(visible);
}
```

**OJO:** Si utilizas JScrollPane, debes tratarlo como tal, reemplazando en el método, así:

```
public void setTableVisible(JScrollPane scroll, boolean visible) {
        scroll.setVisible(visible);
    }
```